# sending rfid data to flask

Tags: rfid

good day !
i am working on a student authentication project in which the student swipes his rfid card over rc522 reader and the laptip webcam captures the photo of the student to authenticate. 
i am using flask for this project.
only thing is that the rfid script will run on the pi and face recognition script will run on the laptop. 
need to know how to send the rfid data over to the flask. 
any help will be appreciated 
thanks!!

Comment: This question has more to do with Python than the Raspberry Pi itself, and is a question regarding how to write a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at MQTT and host the broker on the Pi.

A good intro is [Steves Internet Guide](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt/)

Failing that, you could use sockets programming to link the two together.

[Plenty of examples e.g. this one here](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/socket-programming-in-python-client-server-p2p/)

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a short answer, only with links (link-only answer); explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes.